# How do I link program compiled with MSVC and AddressSanitizer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, address-sanitizer

When I enable Address Sanitizer (ASan) in MSVC,
I get the following linker error while building:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From the *Visual Studio Installer* application, install *Individual component*, "C++ AddressSanizier".